# What does it mean if an LED is 4-DIP?

Tags: led

I understand what it means for an LED to be a DIP LED, but what is a 4-DIP LED?

For example, [here is a 4DIP cool white LED](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=210512828&uq=636132717129381402). Does it just have two leads for the cathode and two for the anode, or do these leads do something else?

Comment: Your link does not work. However you should read the Datasheet.

Comment: From the photos of the white ones, you can tell that the legs are shorted together in pairs (so it still effectively has two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4-DIP is an **almost obsolete** package for "Ultrabright" ( but relatively dim by today's standards )

DIP is the thruhole abbreviation for Dual Inline Package with 4 pins in this case.

[image]

Unlike 5mm they were usually rated for 50mA due to the better heatsink thru the 4 "relative thick pins.  Normally only the Cathode has useful low thermal resistance ['C/W] because the Anode has a micro-thin gold bond wire with very high thermal resistance.

Today SMT LEDs are far superior for thermal resistance, power , efficacy and  colour options

Answer (score 3):

As you suspect, the 4-DIP package has 2 pins for the anode and 2 for the cathode. This allows the LED to hold tighter to a PCB during manufacturing and sink more heat to the board during operation.

[Here is a working link](http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/telux-series-4-pin-square-with-domed-top-leds/35751) to a 4-DIP LED with a datasheet that includes the answer to your question.